# Как добавить файлы в панель add resources в jsfiddle.net?

Tags: javascript

Нажимаю плюс, но ничего не происходит. Может надо зарегистрироваться?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вводите адрес — нажимаете плюс. Через несколько секунд ресурс добавится под полем ввода.

Comment: а куда загружать файлы?

Comment: Там только URL, загрузки файлов там нет. Файлы надо загружать на любой нормально отдающий по HTTP/HTTPS сервер.

Comment: Нормального ответа нет, а вопрос всё ещё в силе, что имеется ввиду под "нормально отдающий по http/https сервер", не первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой загрузки своего файла на jsfiddle, но так и не решилась. Личная виртуальная площадка хостинга похоже не нормально отдающий файлы сервер.